# Django model class creates its own dependencies

Tags: django, database, django-models, foreign-keys, class-method

I have a model that when instantiated, needs to create new instances for its own foreign relationships. Here's an example:

```
class CustomOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

When a new CustomOrder is created,
`CustomOrder.objects.create()`
it needs to create new product and customer instances to fulfill it's foreign key requirements.

Perhaps something like a class method is needed here?

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, base_product):
    product = Product.objects.create()
    customer = Customer.objects.create()
    return cls(product=product, customer=customer)
```

Unfortunately, this class method is not working as designed.

Comment: It seems weird that an order would create a brand new product/customer instead of using existing ones

Comment: a custom order, such as a commissioned piece of art, is for a product that doesn't exist yet. Potentially it may be for a customer we know nothing about yet either if they are just looking for a quick price quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already correct, just create the instance using

`CustomOrder.create()`

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, your code works already. The other way to do this is to put it on the [`Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects)

```
class CustomOrderManager(models.Manager):
    def create_custom_order(self):
        return self.create(product=Product.objects.create(), customer=Customer.objects.create())

class CustomOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)

    objects = CustomOrderManager()

custom_order = CustomOrder.objects.create_custom_order()
```